# Using Mock.Setup on two different methods doesn't match on one and instead returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I am new in Unit Testing. I am using Moq for unit testing. I have a situation where I have to mock for two different method in same section :

I have an Action Method like below :

```
public ActionResult Login(someparameters)
{
   //code...
  var user = userRepository.SelectAllUserByEmail(someparamters); //first method
  //....
  var userDetails = userRepository.ValidateUser(someparameters);//second method
}
```

here is my unit testing part :

```
userrepositoryMock.Setup(r => r.SelectAllUserByEmail(someparameters))
  .Returns(new List<User>() { new User { Salt = strSalt, FundraiserAdminId = fundadmind, StatusCode = statusCode, UserTypeId = userTypeId, HomePageURL = homepageURL, OrganizationId = organizationId } } );

userrepositoryMock.Setup(k => k.ValidateUser(someparamters))
.Returns(new User { Salt = strSalt, FundraiserAdminId = fundadmind, StatusCode = statusCode, UserTypeId = userTypeId, HomePageURL = homepageURL, OrganizationId = organizationId });
```

but this only mocks `SelectAllUserByEmail` method for `ValidateUser` it returns null.

Comment: You should check the parameters passed to methods argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified what type (or types) `someparameters` represent, but I'll bet that at least one of them is a reference type (other than a simple string).

For reference types (like object instances), using Moq's `.Setup` on an exact instance is usually a bad idea, as this will require that the exact same reference is passed to the mocked class in order for the Setup to match and return the provided output.

Here's a simple MVCE which reproduces the problem. Given the following code:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyInterface
{
    string GetUserName(User user);
}
```

The following Unit Test demonstrates that a `Setup` bound to a specific object instance (`aUser`) will *NOT* match if another reference (`sameUser`) is passed to the Mock:

```
[Test]
public void TestGetUserBad()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();

    var aUser = new User { Name = "User1" };
    var sameUser = new User { Name = "User1" };

    mock.Setup(x => x.GetUserName(aUser)).Returns<User>(u => u.Name);

    Assert.AreEqual("User1", mock.Object.GetUserName(aUser), 
        "The mock has been setup for aUser, so this works");
    Assert.AreEqual(null, mock.Object.GetUserName(sameUser), 
        "aUser is a different reference than sameUser hence fails");
}
```

Instead, you should use Moq's `It.Is<>` (with a predicate) or `It.IsAny<>` (any) [matchers](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments) to allow the match for any reference meeting the predicate (if any).

```
[Test]
public void TestGetUserGood()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();

    var aUser = new User { Name = "User1" };
    var sameUser = new User { Name = "User1" };

    mock.Setup(x => x.GetUserName(It.IsAny<User>())).Returns<User>(u => u.Name);

    Assert.AreEqual("User1", mock.Object.GetUserName(aUser), 
        "The mock has been setup for any user, so this works");
    Assert.AreEqual("User1", mock.Object.GetUserName(sameUser), 
        "The mock has been setup for any user, so this works");
}
```

**Edit**

Out of interest, if you suspect one of your Mock setups isn't being matched as intended (as Moq will return `default(T)` when using loose mocking if no match is found), you can temporarily switch [MockBehaviour to Strict](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/MockBehavior.cs#L54), which will throw if a Setup isn't matched.

e.g. applying the below to `TestGetUserBad`

```
var mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

Results in:

> Moq.MockException : IMyInterface.GetUserName(User) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict. All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by adding following code :

```
 userrepositoryMock.SetReturnsDefault(new User { Salt = strSalt, FundraiserAdminId = fundadmind, StatusCode = statusCode, UserTypeId = userTypeId, HomePageURL = homepageURL, OrganizationId = organizationId });
```